# Oracle sql query Order By gives different results

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-order-by

Output of

**Query 1:**

```
select id from users
order by case when DEVIATION_LEVEL=2863 then 1 else 2 end
```

is

```
800019  
800030  
800040  
800003  
800007  
800015  
800025  
800026....etc
```

Output of
**Query 2:**

```
select id from
    (select id from users
     order by case when DEVIATION_LEVEL=2863 then 1 else 2 end)
where rownum<=16;
```

is

```
800019
800030
800028
800020
800021
800018
800012
800161...etc
```

*Why the order changes in 2nd query?* Please suggest correct solution to just limit the size of the first query result.

Comment: There's no ORDER BY in query 2's main query.

Comment: The only numbers that are in both outputs are `800019` & `800030` ... which are in the same order, the other numbers are only in there own respective result sets

Comment: @Matt For Query 1 800040  is at 3rd position. Why it not at 3rd place in the 2nd query. If the problem is with query please suggest the correct solution.

Comment: @sud_shan `800040` isnt in the second query results

Comment: @sud_shan ORDER BY cannot guarantee the ordering with duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a SELECT query without an ORDER BY clause the order of the result is undetermined. If you want or need to have a consistent ordering behavior then use the ORDER BY clause at the top level SELECT.

There is however the exception in oracle when you are limiting the rows with the ROWNUM field. In that case the ROWNUM filter would reduce the result set before applying the order by clause, thus removing rows that should have come first.

```
select id from users
order by case when DEVIATION_LEVEL=2863 then 1 else 2, id;
```

and

```
select id from
    (select id from users
     order by case when DEVIATION_LEVEL=2863 then 1 else 2 end, id)
where rownum<=16;
```

Comment: your solution will destroy the meaning of using 'order by case' in the sub query

Comment: Don't use ORDER BY in a subquery, it is pretty useless to me. Put the thing you want to order on at the top level an order there. It doesn't make sense to order on something and then not provide it to the caller of the query, then you might as well not order at all.

Comment: In general a subquery returns an unordered set, so you would be right. But that's not true for Oracle. The version with `order by` in the subquery is [the recommended solution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

Comment: @Andomar ok thanks to clarify that, not very well known with oracle itself.

Comment: Just to get it off my chest :-): I really hate the ROWNUM idea that oracle has to limit the result set.

Comment: Your second query still won't work. Do a small test yourself, take the EMP table example I posted in my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, due to the row limitation which will reduce the result set prior to the ordering.

Comment: Actually ordering is done in the subquery(inner), and then rownum is applied. So, functionally the query does it's job. However, it is the way ORDER BY is evaluated in the CASE statement is the problem here. Whenever ordering is done on similar values, then there is no guarantee that it will give same ordered set every time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that **ORDER BY cannot guarantee the ordering on duplicate values**.

In your query, put the `DEVIATION_LEVEL` in the column list of the select and then you will understand that the order is just not same when they are duplicate values.

For example,

**Query 1**

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp ORDER BY CASE WHEN deptno=10 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7782         10
      7839         10
      7934         10
      7566         20
      7654         30
      7698         30
      7900         30
      7788         20
      7369         20
      7844         30
      7876         20
      7521         30
      7499         30
      7902         20

14 rows selected.
```

**Query 2**

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp ORDER BY CASE WHEN deptno=10 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
  4    )
  5  WHERE rownum<=5;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7782         10
      7934         10
      7839         10
      7369         20
      7654         30

SQL>
```

So, the ordering in the second case when ROWNUM is applied, it is picked randomly among the similar values.

Look at the first three ordered rows:

**Output 1**

```
     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7782         10
      7839         10
      7934         10
```

**Output 2**

```
     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7782         10
      7934         10
      7839         10
```

ORDER BY deptno will not guarantee same order every time. In above query, if you want a particular order, then make an ORDER BY on another column too, i.e. empno.

```
ORDER BY empno, deptno
```

If you compare both the outputs, there is no guarantee that ordering will be same always since the deptno is same as 10 in all three rows. When you have similar values, and if you order them, it is just like picking them in random.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` in a subquery does not guarantee the results; `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1;` is not same as `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1);`